# Does the use of bit.ly URL shortener prevent social traffic attribution in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client which noticed that the traffic from Twitter did not match up to expectations.they are using bit.ly URLs for all their tweets. Does this affect how traffic is viewed in GA? It looks like it is coming through as Direct.

Comment: It's look [duplicate](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/33478/58259) to me. And the answer is no. Lot's of people block GA(Adblock Browser Extension+ghostery type software), so may be that's the reason.