# Double redirect - referrer in headers

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, http-headers, referrer

let's say we have redirects like this:

**(1)** my shortener link -> **(2)** bit.ly -> **(3)** target URL

Is it possible to check on the end **(3)** that user visit came from **(1)** my shortened link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is traffic coming from URL shorteners treated as direct?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33478/is-traffic-coming-from-url-shorteners-treated-as-direct)

Comment: Does it have to be in the referrer?  Could you instead add tracking parameters (like Google Analytics `utm_*` parameters) to the final URL?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller that's not what I meant

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to check on the end **(3)** that user visit came from **(1)** my shortened link?

No, because "**(1)** my shortened link" is not the referrer. The web page that contains "**(1)** my shortened link" is the referrer and it's this that is *potentially*<sup>***1**</sup> passed down the line by the *browser*.

For example:

1. Webpage-X contains "my-shortener-link" (that is on Domain-A)
2. User clicks on "my-shortener-link" and the browser sends a request to Domain-A. The browser sets Webpage-X as the `Referer`.
3. Domain-A returns a 3xx redirect response to the browser with a `Location` header pointing to `bit.ly`.
4. The browser sends a request to `bit.ly`, again setting Webpage-X as the `Referer`, since it remembers that Webpage-X started this process to begin with.
5. `bit.ly` returns a 3xx redirect response to the browser with a `Location` header pointing to the target-URL.
6. The browser sends a request to the target-URL, again setting Webpage-X as the `Referer`, since it remembers...

The server at target-URL only knows (potentially) that the request originated from Webpage-X that contained the original link. It does not know the nature of that link or the fact that several redirects occurred on the way to get there.

<sup>***1**</sup> I say potentially, since the [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) at any redirect along the way could restrict how much of the referrer (`Referer` header) gets passed on by the browser.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know if (1) my shortener link could be exposed somehow along the way... Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question then please mark it as "accepted".  Thanks, much appreciated. :)