# There is a way to block a access to a page if user typing the url?

Tags: php

I have a php page A which redirects to page B. I have a shortlink on page A. I want access to be denied to A unless the user accesses from the shortlink.

The problem is that the shortlink creation site is blocking the USER WEB AGENT HTTP_REFERER. So I can't tell if the user comes from the shortlink on page A.

So the user can just write the url of page A to be redirected to page B without going through the shortlink.

Is there a way or idea to avoid redirecting the user to B if he has access to A through the url or other than the shortlink ?

Comment: What is the purpose of blocking users in this case?

Comment: I couldn't use the REFERER on page B, so I created a new page A and so to access B you have to come from A, except that A is accessible from the url. The goal is that in B, I have a key generator that starts automatically if we access the page, and I want the user to generate a key only by accessing through the shortlink which is the shortcut link of the page A (page A gonna make a redirection to B and generate a key)

Comment: What is this key used for? It sounds like you might need a better security system than what you were proposing.

Comment: I do not know the exact use of this key but I would like to know the affordable solutions for this kind of logic

Comment: "I have a php page A which redirects to page B. I have a shortlink on page A." - So, the "shortlink" _redirects_ to "page A"? Why not redirect directly to "page B"? Is "page A" performing some other action?

Comment: in page B I generate a key. If I go directly to page B I pass the protection and I generate a key without going through the shortlink. So I put the shortlink on page A in order to know if in page B I arrived by page A before and not directly on B. So I have minimal protection, but now I would like to make protection for those which are a little advanced and put directly the link of the page A how can I do it?

Comment: "I put the shortlink on page A" - What exactly do you mean by this? How is this implemented? Is "page B" on an entirely different site? I'm kind of struggling with why you need the "shortlink" in the first place or even why you need to "redirect" to page B? I'm guessing the "shortlink" just _obfuscates_ page A? Can page A not make a direct (server to server) request to page B to retrieve the "key"?

Comment: A and B are on the same website. "I put the sortlink on page A" - I create a shortlink redirect to the page A. I need two page because i don't know if the referer is from the shortlinker website, because the http_referer is empty from it. So i create another page A to make the shortlinker redirect to this page. And in this page i redirect to the page B who gonna generate a key only if the referer http is the page A.

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is that the shortlink creation site is blocking the USER
> WEB AGENT HTTP_REFERER. So I can't tell if the user comes from the
> shortlink on page A.

The "shortlink creation site" probably isn't blocking anything. When a URL is typed directly into the browser there is no `Referer`. A 3xx redirection does not create a `Referer`.

It is not possible for "Page B" to determine whether the request was *redirected* from "page A" or from the *shortlink*, if the user manually typed the URL, since there is no `Referer` to begin with. The only way to determine the source of the redirect (at "B") is if something was appended to the redirected URL that "page B" can check for. eg. A benign query string: `?redirect=shortlink`.

See also:
[Double redirect - referrer in headers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132183/double-redirect-referrer-in-headers)

> Is there a way or idea to avoid redirecting the user to B if he has access to A through the url or other than the shortlink ?

Check the URL being requested?

Comment: in fact, I agree that maybe the website of shortened links does not block the http_referer, but by clicking on the button to get to my page, there is surely a redirect which makes my page the http_referer is empty (not isset), how could they do that? Maybe by modifying the http_referer. If I add a query string in the url, well the user can always add this string in the url

Comment: @Meds,instead of querystring that a user can deciper, what about using your own hash/algorithm that uses a timestamp.  Your secondary server can test if the provided querystring matches a timestamp that is less than 30 seconds old.

Comment: "clicking on the button to get to my page" - where is this "button", it is standard HTML "link"? Check the network traffic in the browser - is the `Referer` HTTP request header set by the browser on the initial request? What is the nature of the redirect chain? The passing of the `Referer` can be controlled by the source website (that contains the link) by setting a [Referrer-Poilcy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy). The redirect service could also destroy the `Referer` by going via an intermediary link that sets a Referrer-Policy.

Comment: However, "shortlink/redirect" creation sites generally do not do this. If they have the option to remove the `Referer` then this would be an additional service. In general, it is in everyone's interests that the original `Referer` remains intact. All the main shortlink services that I'm aware of preserve the HTTP `Referer`.

Comment: The shortlinker is linkvertise. "clicking on the button to get to my page" - there is a button but i don't see any action or form tag, or a href link. The link is https://linkvertise.com/200619/Testing2?o=sharing  -- Can u tell me more about the horodatage logic please ?

Comment: When you say encrypt the querystring, I could not do that because it would be necessary to encrypt the url of the shortlink, which is not possible since I enter in the field a simple url which will be converted into a shortlink